# Find the perpendicular projection to an intersection line

Tags: calculus, linear-algebra, multivariable-calculus

Let K be the intersection curve of surfaces

$M_1 : x^2+y^2-5z^3=8$

and

$M_2 : 8x^2-2y^2+6z^3=20$

Give a cartesian equation for the perpendicular projection $K_0$ of the curve K on the $(x,y)$-plane

How can I start this problem?

Comment: take $6M_1 + 5 M_2$  to get an equation with no appearance of $z$

Comment: Thanks this solved it :)